# Was Luke Skywalker based on George Lucas?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, inspiration, george-lucas

It isn't uncommon to see people claiming or joking that the character of Luke Skywalker was based on George Lucas.

For example, *[George Lucas in Love](https://vimeo.com/129810820)* and [this *Onion* article](http://www.theonion.com/blogpost/the-events-depicted-in-star-wars-actually-happened-32560).

I can see where this is coming from as they do seem to have some similarities.

For example:

- The names (Lucas and Luke)
- George drag-raced when he was younger, Luke raced spaceships and speeders.
- Both were raised in the desert.

So has Lucas, anyone close to him or anyone involved with the creation of *Star Wars* ever stated whether or not the character of Luke was based on or inspired by Lucas himself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes, admittedly so.

According to ***A Brief a Guide to Star Wars*** by Brian J. Robb:

> As he had poured much of his teenage self into several characters in *American Graffiti*, so the young hero of *Star Wars* — Luke Skywalker — was very much another George Lucas alter-ego.

([Source](https://books.google.ca/books?id=i9jABAAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=george+lucas+on+inspiration+luke+skywalker+on+himself&source=bl&ots=qLySqbA1DU&sig=7iwLpNjfg6kIrLr2xldFyfY8Bz0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX4LnOmt_LAhUhuYMKHRuNARI4ChDoAQguMAg#v=onepage&q=george%20lucas%20on%20inspiration%20luke%20skywalker%20on%20himself&f=false))

Robb specifically mentions Lucas' desert upbringing (referring to Tatooine as "the Modesto of this galaxy far, far away"), his desire for adventure, and his refusal to follow in his father's footsteps as a stationary store clerk.

Robb then quotes Lucas directly on the matter:

> **"You can't write a main character and not have him be part of you,"** admitted Lucas.

Comment: Hmmm… all of the points here (except the one about the father) could equally well apply to Anakin—the drag-racing bit from the question even better with Anakin than with Luke. More importantly, I think most here would agree that Lucas definitely turned to the Dark Side in the prequels. I conclude that Anakin is George Lucas!